# Use apply instead of nested for loop with if statement

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I want to compare the text of one row with all of the following rows in order to find the deviations.
How can the code below be converted into code without using a for loop?

```
dat <- data.frame(n = seq(1, 19, by = 1),
des = c("Some very long text", "Some very lang test", "Some vary long text", "Some veri long text", "Another very long text", "Anather very long text", "Another very long text", "Different text", "Diferent text", "More text", "More test", "Much more text", "Muh more text", "Some other long text", "Some otoher long text", "Some more text", "Same more text", "New text", "New texd"))

dat <- dat[!duplicated(dat[,c('des')]),]

column <- which(names(dat) == "des")
dupli <- rep(FALSE, nrow(dat))
for (lin in 1:(nrow(dat)-1)){
  for (other in (lin+1):nrow(dat))
  {
    if (stringdist( dat[lin, column], dat[other, column]) < 2)  
       dupli[lin] <- TRUE       
  }         
}
```

I would like to speed up the process, because I have a lot of text in about 5000 rows. I want to compare row 1 with row 2 to 19 and so on. So the for loop is very slow with 5000 rows. Is it possible to use some apply function instead?

Comment: You probably want something like this: `require(dplyr)` ; `dat %>% mutate(dist = ifelse(stringdist(des,lead(des))<3,TRUE,FALSE))`

Comment: Just `with(dat, stringdist(head(des, -1), tail(des, -1))) < 3` should do

Comment: @DavidArenburg my dataset has 5000 rows. I think it's not possible to solve the problem with head and tail.

Comment: Why not? You want to compare each row with the preceding one, no? This does exactly that. Have you even tried that or you just assuming?

Comment: I assumed. But now I tried it. Your code works well. Thanks! But it returns one element less than the for loop. The last element your code returns is a TRUE. The loop returns a FALSE.

Comment: In your `dupli` vector you have an extra element that you set to `FALSE` by default. The result can't be of the same length as the original data set because you are not comparing your last observation with anything. Hence, `dupli` should be something like `dupli <- rep(FALSE, nrow(dat) - 1)`.

Comment: Eitehr-way, two things you must memorize when working with R: 1- R is vectorized- so think vector, not loops. `for` loop is the same as `apply` and many times better (because stuff like to matrix conversion and etc. which `apply` does underneath).

Comment: But I can't figure out how to convert the code into an apply using code. I need `length(dat)` elements of dupli in order to `cbind(dat,dupli)`.

Comment: Could do something like `dat$res <- c(with(dat, stringdist(head(des, -1), tail(des, -1))) < 3, NA)`

Comment: My problem is, that I want to detect duplicates including those which have typos. The last element of `dat` is a duplicate with typo of the previous element. The loop produces FALSE for the last element and indeed it is a false duplicate.

Comment: I have no idea what you talking about. Do you just want an arbitrary `FALSE` at the end of the vector? So just replace the `NA` with `FALSE` in my previous comment. Other that than I have no idea what else I can help you with.

Comment: I thought about it and edited my question again. I want to compare the first row with all the following rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
library(stringdist)
dat <- data.frame(n = 1:19, des = c("Some very long text", "Some very lang test", "Some vary long text", "Some veri long text", "Another very long text", "Anather very long text", "Another very long text", "Different text", "Diferent text", "More text", "More test", "Much more text", "Muh more text", "Some other long text", "Some otoher long text", "Some more text", "Same more text", "New text", "New texd"))

column <- which(names(dat) == "des")
N <- nrow(dat)

#change outer loop to sapply
dupli <- c(sapply(1:(N-1), function(row){
    #change inner loop to arraywise processing and aggregate with any
    any(stringdist(dat[row, column], dat[(row+1):N, column]) < 2)
}), FALSE)
```

Not that fast, but faster than a plain for loop. `cbind(dat, dupli)` would than give

```
    n                    des dupli
1   1    Some very long text  TRUE
2   2    Some very lang test FALSE
3   3    Some vary long text FALSE
4   4    Some veri long text FALSE
5   5 Another very long text  TRUE
6   6 Anather very long text  TRUE
7   7 Another very long text FALSE
8   8         Different text  TRUE
9   9          Diferent text FALSE
10 10              More text  TRUE
11 11              More test FALSE
12 12         Much more text  TRUE
13 13          Muh more text FALSE
14 14   Some other long text  TRUE
15 15  Some otoher long text FALSE
16 16         Some more text  TRUE
17 17         Same more text FALSE
18 18               New text  TRUE
19 19               New texd FALSE
```

Comment: Your code is much more faster than the for loop. Thank you very much!